# How do I fix an internal server error when authenticating with Next-Auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to add authentication to my Next.js project with Next-Auth. However, I am stuck on a `500 internal server error` after submitting credentials (`http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Configuration`).

I think it might be something to do with running on *http://localhost:3000*, but I'm not sure. What I'm doing wrong?

**pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';

const options = {
  site: 'http://localhost:3000',

  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text', placeholder: 'jsmith' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        consol.log('credentials', credentials);
        const user = { id: 1, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' };
        if (user) {
          return Promise.resolve(user);
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(null);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  database: process.env.MONGO_URI,
};

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```

**pages/index.js**

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client';

export default function Home() {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();
  console.log('session', session);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <main>
          {session && <p>Signed in as {session.user.email}</p>}
          {!session && (
            <p>
              <a href="/api/auth/signin">Sign in</a>
            </p>
          )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**pages/_app.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client';
import '../styles.css';

export default ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const { session } = pageProps;
  return (
    <Provider options={{ site: process.env.SITE }} session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    MONGO_URI: '...',
    SITE: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
};
```

Comment: Philip Loosemore pointed out in an answer that there is a typo in the first section of code where `console.log` is written `consol.log`. They indicate that this typo could cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Did you find what the problem was? Thanks

Comment: @Armel I honestly cant remember, it was a fair while ago. I think it may have been an issue with JWT (or the fact i wasn't using one!). Or could be the `consol.log ` issue Jason mentioned above

Comment: No worries @ThomasAllen, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

In your `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file, add:

```
secret:process.env.SECRET
```

`SECRET` must be any string value like this:

```
SECRET:LlKq6ZtYbr+hTC073mAmAh9/h2HwMfsFo4hrfCx6gts=
```

Also, add it in your Vercel environment.
that’s it; your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned by Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937146/how-do-i-fix-an-internal-server-error-when-authenticating-with-next-auth/70348538#70348538), my problem was solved by adding a `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` to both Vercel environment variables and to `[...nextauth].ts`.

A local deployment worked without that variable, but Vercel deployment needed the secret. In addition to adding the Vercel environment variable, my working `[...nextauth].ts` looks like:

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token }) {
      token.userRole = "user"
      return token
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo under your asyc function  `consol.log('credentials', credentials);`

Fix to  `console.log('credentials', credentials);` and that should solve the problem.

I faced a similar problem and it was because I didn't add any `providers` array.

In the future, fix any typos or errors within your `[...nextauth].js` to fix `500 error`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind NEXTAUTH_URL to be set for yourwebsite.com

process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL=https://yourwebsite.com

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only required if you host your site somewhere NOT on vercel (https://next-auth.js.org/deployment#vercel). It says: "You do not need the NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable in Vercel."